# Error installing grub on bootable USB drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to deliver a Linux tool as a bootable USB stick and so I am trying to create a USB stick with the Ubuntu core. I am following the steps at [What commands are needed to install Ubuntu Core?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67001/what-commands-are-needed-to-install-ubuntu-core)

But when I run the command `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt
/dev/sda`, I get this error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

I did a some research on the internet and could not get any answers.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is unlikely that the usb is named /dev/sda. Check the name of the usb with this command: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb*`. As for the grub command, it is a bit limited. In my experience you have to specify the target as well. the command would be `grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sd*`. In `/dev/sd* ` the * would be the device identifier, a letter from a-z.

Comment: Agreed, `sda` is almost always your primary hard disk.

Comment: Also, you do not need to install Ubuntu Core to install grub on a thumb drive to use a tool on the drive. Just create an iso that runs the tool and install grub on the usb and have it run the iso.

Comment: that was just and example actually it is /dev/sde

Comment: Another cause could be that you haven't specified a boot partition. You can create one with the  offset of 1.7Kb left behind after you created the first partition on the usb drive. The code for a bios boot partition is ef02 (eg. linux partition is 8300). After creating it run `grub-install` again.

Comment: What does it tell before that error? Looks like `grub` cannot find space to install itself.